# Lag when calling a function on resize inside itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Is there a better/more straightforward way of doing this?

```
function moveNav(){
   var navOffset = $(".nav-marker").offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scrollOffset = $(document).scrollTop();
      if( scrollOffset >= navOffset ){
         $(".nav-bar").addClass("scroll-fixed");
      } else{
         $(".nav-bar").removeClass("scroll-fixed");
      }
    });
}
moveNav();
// call again on resize to recompute navOffset
$(window).resize(function() {
  moveNav();
});
```

I want to use the `moveNav()` function again when the browser is resized but the way I'm currently doing it feels off. I feel like there's a way of moving the `resize()` function inside the `moveNav()` function but when I put it inside it, there's some lag happening when when I resize. You can see it happening here: https://jsfiddle.net/grj89t9b/2/

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Comment: Oh I think I pasted the wrong fiddle. Updated it just now.

Comment: Plus, you’re attaching a new scroll handler every time the window is resized, so they’ll keep adding up.

Comment: "Debounce"-ing actions can be beneficial too https://davidwalsh.name/function-debounce

Comment: @CBroe, @smcd I encountered these problems when I tried to do an `alert()` on scroll so thanks for the links! What it would do totally skipped my head. Tried it but had to set the interval lower to make the delay on the nav "sticking" unperceivable.

Comment: +1 for debouncing window resize events. You need a buffer delay, otherwise, it's going to call that function A LOT, VERY FAST.

Answer (score 0):

I would declare the variables first, and make a simpler function but then declare it both on `$(window).resize()` and `$(document).scroll()`.

```
var navOffset, scrollOffset;
function moveNav(){
    navOffset = $(".nav-marker").offset().top;
    scrollOffset = $(document).scrollTop();
    if( scrollOffset >= navOffset ){
        $(".nav-bar").addClass("scroll-fixed");
    } else {
        $(".nav-bar").removeClass("scroll-fixed");
    }
}
moveNav();
$(document).scroll(function() { moveNav(); });
$(window).resize(function() { moveNav(); });
```

and it works on your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/grj89t9b/4/).